# Trying to use JarBundler on my Mac OSX system

Tags: java, macos, ant, jar, bundler

I am trying to use the JarBundler ant plugin but it doesn't see the class. See this:

```
Marisas-Mini:ThudNG-1.0 fstltna$ ant
Buildfile: /Users/fstltna/Documents/ThudNG2/ThudNG2/ThudNG-1.0/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/Users/fstltna/Documents/ThudNG2/ThudNG2/ThudNG-1.0/build.xml:62: taskdef class net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler cannot be found
using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Please help!

I still get this error:
    BUILD FAILED
    /Users/fstltna/Documents/ThudNG2/ThudNG2/ThudNG-1.0/build.xml:63: taskdef class net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler cannot be found
    using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Here is the section from my build.xml:

```
<taskdef name="jarbundler"
    classpath="~/.ant/lib/jarbundler-core-3.3.0.jar"
    classname="net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler" />
```

and in the definition:

```
<jarbundler
        build="3.1.0"
        bundleid="com.mekcity.thudng2"
        copyright="(C) 2016 - Mek City"
        icon="foo.png"
        infostring="The Battletech MUX client ThudNG2"
        shortname="ThudNG2"
        signature="TNG2"
        version="3.1.0"
        dir="release"
        name="ThudNG2"
        mainclass="=ThudNG-1.0/src&lt;net.sourceforge.btthud.ui{Thud.java[Thud"
        jar="Thud.jar" />
```

Comment: check `classpath` element of `taskdef` in `build.xml`. that shold point to the jar file where net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler class exists.

Comment: what happens when you give full path of jar file `jarbundler-core-3.3.0.jar` like `/home/xxx/.ant/lib/jarbundler-core-3.3.0.jar`

Comment: That is what I am seeing...

Comment: ok, what do you get when run `ls -la /home/xxx/.ant/lib/jarbundler-core-3.3.0.jar` ?

Comment: -rw-r--r--@ 1 fstltna  staff  22946 Oct  9 00:12 /Users/fstltna/.ant/lib/jarbundler-core-3.3.0.jar

Comment: thanks, then what you get when run `unzip -l /Users/fstltna/.ant/lib/jarbundler-core-3.3.0.jar`